# Sencha Dashboard - ExtJS 6 - dynamically adding parts and reading config

Tags: javascript, extjs, dashboard, extjs6-classic

I have an Ext JS 6 app with a dashboard with 4 configured parts.
the defaultContent (which the user starts with) has two of these parts included, the others are meant to be optional.

If a users adds one or more of the optional parts, how can I get this configuration to save it to a database?

I have tried with getParts() - it only gives me the possible 4 parts defined in parts.

I have Tried reading the defaultConfig after adding parts, but is gives me what the page loaded with.

Here is a fiddle that show this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1mb9&view/editor

After clicking on one of the buttons, I'd like to have the config of the dashboard with which parts are currently in the dashboard. Can't find how to do that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getState()` to retreive the current state of the dashboard including the current items and how they are configured.  Similarly, `setState()` can be used to restore the state.  See the explanation of `stateful` [in the extJS docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard.html#cfg-stateful).